# MMDrawerController touch on UISlider applied to the wrong view on iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uislider

I have a UITableView with three cells and one UISlider on each of them.
In order to allow for both the pan-to-open drawer gesture and the sliders, the custom gestures block looks like the below:

```
[dcDrawer setGestureShouldRecognizeTouchBlock:^BOOL(MMDrawerController *drawerController, UIGestureRecognizer *gesture, UITouch *touch) {
     return !([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UISlider class]]) && [gesture isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]];
}];
```

This was working fine on iOS 6 but with iOS 7 every time I try to use ANY of the sliders the slider on the FIRST cell gets the touch.

Completely lost as to where the issue lays. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I disabled the panning for the whole view and the strange behaviour on the sliders is still happening.

**EDIT 2:**

I figured it out. In the end it didn't have anything to do with MMDrawerViewController. When one of the sliders was moved, I was calling a method that got the cell the slider was in and updated the associated label. Because of the new view in the structure of UITableViewCell on iOS 7, I was always getting row 0. Needed to add an additional [[ ... ] superview] in this case.

Answer (score 0):

As per my edit on the first post above.